# The array is showing the count number not $name

Tags: php, arrays

This is through a codecadamey tutorial and it does not explain fully or has no source with the correct code for me to find so that is why I am posting here. I have already tried to post in their forums but have not got a conveniently speedy or correct answer like I would here.

Here is the code that is affiliated with the 'project' :

```
<html>
<p>
<?php
// Create an array and push on the names
// of your closest family and friends
$names = array();
array_push($names, "brittany"); 
array_push($names, "nane");
array_push($names, "pops");
array_push($names, "timothy");
array_push($names, "patrick");
array_push($names, "cyndie");
array_push($names, "dad");
array_push($names, "mindy");
array_push($names, "gunner");
array_push($names, "nick");
array_push($names, "mark");
array_push($names, "scott");
array_push($names, "joe");
array_push($names, "dodi");
array_push($names, "cory");
array_push($names, "joey");
array_push($names, "taylor");
array_push($names, "tony");
array_push($names, "lynn");
array_push($names, "ella");
array_push($names, "zachary");
array_push($names, "corey");

count($names);    
// Sort the list
sort($names);
// Randomly select a winner!
$winner = rand(0, 21);
// Print the winner's name in ALL CAPS
print strtoupper($winner);
?>
</p>
```

The outcome of this code SHOULD display a name that is within the $names array (array_push) but it does not. The outcome of this code only displays a number in between 1 and 22.

For example what I am seeing in the preview screen is something like this:

```
9
```

All answers and responses are very much appreciated!

Best regards,
Codi

Comment: Debug it.. You know $winner has the wrong value. So where does $winner come from? `rand()`.. you should check the docs for the return value of rand and see why it's giving you a number instead of a value from your array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are just displaying the random number.

Try

```
print strtoupper($names[$winner]);
```

And you want to use the `$count` minus 1 as the upper bounds of the `rand()`:

```
// Count the list
$count = count($names);    
// Sort the list
sort($names);
// Randomly select a winner!
$winner = rand(0, $count - 1);
// Print the winner's name in ALL CAPS
print strtoupper($names[$winner]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Winner is just a number between 1 and 21. You need the value of the array:

```
echo $names[$winner];
echo $names[ rand(0,21) ];
```

I suggest you change your code to a bit better maintainable code:

```
$names = array('joe','john','martin', 'Thor');
$contestants = count($names); // now we know the amount of names
$winner = rand(0, $contestants-1); // use the amount of names (minus 1 for 0-based index)
echo $names[$winner]; // echo the name
```

Comment: Oh, Should've clicked "check one new answer"

Comment: Oh, and now his edit contains my complete answer -_-